# Is it possible to tamper CloudFront-Viewer-Address value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cloudfront

I've prepared a site which only executes phpinfo(), and the result of the following shows that XFF can be tampered with, but not CloudFront-Viewer-Address value, which has the correct external IP.

CloudFront-Viewer-Address value are impossible to tamper, i.e., is it safe to trust this value for IP restrictions? Or can it be tampered with in some way? (If the latter, can you tell me what the possible cases are?)

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.jp:443 -servername example.jp

GET / HTTP/1.1
HOST: example.jp
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.10.1, 10.0.1.2
cloudfront-viewer-address: 10.0.1.3
cloudfront-viewer_address: 10.0.1.3
cloudfront_viewer-address: 10.0.1.3
cloudfront_viewer_address: 10.0.1.3
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be tampered with in the same way that `x-forwarded-for` because if an attacker adds it, CloudFront will simply overwrite it.

It's well known enough that many attackers will mess with it vs a custom header or a Cloudfront header.
With x-forwarded-for, you can also end up with more than one header:value pair or more than one value. Either is a problem because how will your code know which one to check?

Of course you can configure a proxy like nginx to overwrite any/all x-forwarded-for headers but, we're talking about using AWS services here and don't need to add yet another proxy.

BTW: it's recommended *not* to prefix custom headers with `x-`nowadays: https://tonyxu.io/posts/2018/http-deprecate-x-prefix/

Answer (score 0):

Tampered with in a way that causes problems for you?  Depends on configuration.  If your origin is configured in a way that it only allows traffic from Amazon CloudFront endpoints and drops all other requests (a firewall or IP restrictions at the webserver would be ways to do this, with firewall recommended), then no it cannot be tampered with.  CloudFront will always send this header if configured to, so any tampering attempts will get overwritten by CloudFront, as Chris Thompson says, and any attempts to bypass CloudFront will be dropped by the firewall.